# Python : AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'is_open' for real time data

Tags: python, port

hello i have a problem with my current code. i want to plot a real time signal for my ecg from my udoo. buat when i connect the serial it getting like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_serial.py", line 10, in <module>
    if userial.is_open:
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'is_open'
```

here's my code :

```
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ubaudrate = 9600
uport = '/dev/ttyMCC'  # set the correct port before run it
userial = serial.Serial(uport, ubaudrate, timeout=1)
userial.timeout = 10 
if userial.is_open:
    while True:
        size = userial.inWaiting()
        if size:
            data = userial.read(size)
            plt.figure
            plt.plot(size, data, 'b', alpha=0.75)
            plt.legend(('Sinyal Jantung'), loc='best')
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.show()

            #print data
        else:
            print ('no data')
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print ('serial not open')
# z1serial.close()  # close z1serial if z1serial is open.
```

thanks for your help before, since i'm newbie in python programming

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using older version of pySerial. You can either get later version of pySerial, or use isOpen() to replace is_open.

The data from serial.read is likely str, so you need to convert it into numeric.

```
data = np.float64(np.frombuffer(data.encode(), 'B'))
```

This supposes each byte of the data represents a point.

I also see another problem in your code to plot. You may drop the first input 'size', like

```
plt.plot(data, 'b', alpha=0.75)
```

Comment: thanks before dude, but i get another error like this 
`File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 743, in   get_path
     self.recache()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 429, in recache
    y = np.asarray(yconv, np.float_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 336`                                                                 do you know how to fix it?